# SQL help getting back results from an empty, how to do?

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

I have 2 tables:

course (coursecode, name, description, points)

results (studentnr, coursecode, teachernr, grade, date)

I am trying to do the following:

Enter the course code and course name of all courses,
for which a grade result is not achieved by any student.

```
SELECT DISTINCT course.coursecode, results.coursecode
FROM course, results
WHERE results.grade = 0.0
GROUP BY course.coursecode
```

Comment: Or in other words, you are looking to see where the `SUM` of a `coursecode` grouped by `coursecode` has (i.e. `HAVING`) the value of `0` ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT course.coursecode, SUM(results.coursecode) AS sum_course
FROM course, results
WHERE results.coursecode = course.coursecode
GROUP BY course.coursecode
HAVING sum_course = 0
```